# Young's inequality implies $L^p$ convergence of convolution

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am reading a material which states:

If $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $g \in L^P(\mathbb{R})$. Then $f_n*g \to f*g$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ by Young's inequality.

But I cannot see why Young's inequality implies this immediately. Can anyone show me the idea? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Young's Inequality says that:

$$\|f*g\|_r\leq c_{p,q}\|f\|_p\|g\|_q,$$

where $1/p+1/q=1/r+1$. Take $r=p,q=1$, giving:

$$\|f_n*g-f*g\|_p=\|(f_n-f)*g\|_p\leq \|f_n-f\|_1\|g\|_p,$$

and now use the fact that $\|f_n-f\|_1\rightarrow 0$ by assumption.

Comment: Oh yeah! I should think of this... Thank you so much!